# Using regexp with etags to parse customized definitions

Tags: regex, perl, exuberant-ctags

I have a perl file where some functions are defined using special syntax (Mojolicious):

```
$app->helper('helper1' => sub {
            print "Hello 1";
        });

$app->helper("helper2" => sub {
            print "Hello 2";
        });

$app->helper(helper3 => sub {
            print "Hello 3";
        });

helper1();
helper2();
helper3();
```

I managed to create the Perl regexp to capture these definitions:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp 'read_file';

my $code = read_file('helpers.pl');

my @matches = $code =~ /\$app\->helper\(['"]?(.*?)['"]? => sub/g;
foreach(@matches)
{
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Output:

```
helper1
helper2
helper3
```

But my attempt to use it in etags failed;

```
etags -l perl --regex="/\$app\->helper\\\(['\"]\(.*?\)['\"] => sub/" ./helpers.pl
```

Gives an empty TAGS file. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal Ctags just introduced pcre2 as an optional regular expression engine.
If you build a ctags executable from the latest code in the git repository (git clone https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags.git) with pcre2, you can use non-greedy match. That means the command line Andreas Louv showed may work well.

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.pl                                                                                                                                                                             
$app->helper('helper1' => sub {                                                                                                                                                               
            print "Hello 1";                                                                                                                                                                  
        });                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                              
$app->helper("helper2" => sub {                                                                                                                                                               
            print "Hello 2";                                                                                                                                                                  
        });                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                              
$app->helper(helper3 => sub {                                                                                                                                                                 
            print "Hello 3";                                                                                                                                                                  
        });                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                              
helper1();                                                                                                                                                                                    
helper2();                                                                                                                                                                                    
helper3();                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                              
$ ./ctags -o - --regex-perl='/\$app->helper\(['\''"]?(.*?)['\''"]? => sub/\1/s/{pcre2}' /tmp/foo.pl                                                                                           
helper1 /tmp/foo.pl     /^$app->helper('helper1' => sub {$/;"   s                                                                                                                             
helper2 /tmp/foo.pl     /^$app->helper("helper2" => sub {$/;"   s                                                                                                                             
helper3 /tmp/foo.pl     /^$app->helper(helper3 => sub {$/;"     s                                                                                                                             
$ ./ctags -e --regex-perl='/\$app->helper\(['\''"]?(.*?)['\''"]? => sub/\1/s/{pcre2}' /tmp/foo.pl                                                                                             
$ cat TAGS                                                                                                                                                                                    
^L                                                                                                                                                                                            
/tmp/foo.pl,133                                                                                                                                                                               
$app->helper('helper1' => sub {^?helper1^A1,0                                                                                                                                                 
$app->helper("helper2" => sub {^?helper2^A5,74                                                                                                                                                
$app->helper(helper3 => sub {^?helper3^A9,148                                                                                                                                                 
$
```

You can verify you whether pcre2 is linked to your ctags or not.

```
$ ./ctags --list-features | grep pcre2
pcre2             has pcre2 regex engine
$
```

Comment: I built it from github, but there is no pcre2 support: checked with your command. How to enable it while compiling?

Comment: pcre2 must be installed. The configure script in the source tree of ctags may detect it. If you have a trouble, open an issue at https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/issues .

Comment: After rebuilding universal ctags on Ubuntu with pcre2 your regexp started to work.

Comment: Now I need to add another regexp: `->add_condition\(\s*['\''"]?(.*?)['\''"]?\s+=>\s*sub`. Is it possible to create a file for Perl so when ctags does Perl parsing it would use multiple regexps?

Comment: Put the options to ~/.ctags.d/myperl.ctags like https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/blob/80753d68d11926608f4d998b7f83964af7540562/optlib/passwd.ctags#L33 . NOTE: escaping sequences for shell are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems is your shell escapes, eg:

- `"\$xxx"` will end up being to `$xxx` which means EOL in regex.
- `"\-"` will in a POSIX shell expand to `\-`.

You should use single quoted string to hold your pattern, as the only special character in single quotes are single quotes. If the pattern should be:

```
/\$app->helper\(['"](.*?)['"] => sub/
```

Then the single quote string would be:

```
'/\$app->helper\(['\''"](.*?)['\''"] => sub/'
```

I don't use exuberant-ctags, but Universal Ctags which is never. In Universal Ctags one would need to write:

```
/\$app->helper\(['"](.*)['"] => sub/\1/
```

Notice how the non-greedy modifier isn't supported, and how I provided the keyword creation part: `\1/` after the pattern.

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to enclose the above pattern in single quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately, your regexp gives an error: `etags -l perl --regex='/\$app->helper\(['\''"](.*?)['\''"] => sub/' ./helpers.pl` -> `etags: Unmatched ( or \( while compiling pattern`.

Comment: It seems like etags uses BRE regex? maybe you can specify a flag to enable ERE? Otherwise you'll need to provide a BRE pattern. https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html

Comment: ok, I tried universal ctags, but TAGS file is still empty: `/usr/local/bin/ctags --langmap=perl:.pm.pl --languages=perl --regex-perl='/\$app->helper\(['\''"](.*)['\''"] => sub/\1/' ./helpers.pl`.

Comment: Add -e option generating TAGS output in Universal Ctags.

Comment: Introducing pcre2 including non-greedy modifier to Universal Ctags is work in progress. See https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/pull/3036 .